# Обтекание фигуру текстом алгоритм

Tags: c#, алгоритм, текст

Хочу найти или создать алгоритм наложение текста на фигуру. ( Как это делается в играх-стратегиях ( hoi4, ck и т.п ) ( скрин прилагается ). Не важно какой язык, если что смогу переписать не нужный мне. Главное найти или описать алгоритм, который бы трансформировал текст под нужную мне фигуру. [image: Что-то похожее не это]

Comment: Франция явно плохо получилась на картинке. По идее у вас есть пятна областей, их центры. Размещайте туда текст и увеличивайте до границ. Добавьте повороты, если области сиьно вытянутые.

Comment: Да, но это лучше, чем если бы текст был бы горизонтально ( тогда бы он был маленький и слабо читаемый )

Comment: Дело вкуса. Лично мне вертикальный текст на "квадратной" стране кажется явно не к месту ) Лучше бы диагонально ии горизонтально - размер почти одинаковый был бы.

Comment: Первая буква на строго вертикальном тексте должна быть внизу.